# Basis of Even/Odd Functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

> Find a basis for all of the even polynomials and all of the odd polynomials in $P_4(R)$.

So, firstly, I know that a function is called even if f(−x) = f(x) for all x, and a function is called odd if f(−x) = −f(x) for all x. Thus, an odd function will have some leading coefficient like a$x^n$, where n is odd (and vice-versa for even). However, finding a basis for this is tricky. Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $P_4(\mathbb{R})$ has (standard) basis
$$
\{ 1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}
$$
Which of these do you need to describe even polynomials? What happens if you throw an odd degree term in?

Comment: You only need x^2 to describe even polynomials, because every other possible solution is a factor of that, right?

Comment: this is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, you are not allowed to multiply the vectors, which is what it sounds like you want to do.

Comment: also, a constant polynomial even